# Wigner $D$ matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, symmetry, group-representations

How to derive symmetry relation of [Wigner $D$ matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Definition_of_the_Wigner_D-matrix)? I mean this relation
$$    
D_{m',m}^j (\alpha,\beta,\gamma) 
= (-1)^{m'-m} D_{-m',-m}^j (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)^*.
$$
I want to derive this, but I don't know how. Anyone derive this, please.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations in your questions. I've edited this one for you as an example. In the process I've corrected an apparent error, changing $1$ to $(-1)$, you might want to double check that this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page that you linked to explains, at the end of the section “Properties of the Wigner D-matrix”, that this property is a consequence of the commutation of the rotation matrix with the time reversal operator $T$. The derivation is given there.